# Emacs Ispell to list all spelling errors at once

Tags: flyspell, ispell, spell-checking, writing

I am using emacs `ispell` to look for spelling mistakes. It works well in interactive mode, but I was wondering if I can see all the words with spelling issues highlighted in the buffer itself or highlighted in a separate buffer. I need this because a lot of my writing involves use of technical nouns that aren't in the dictionary and it is a little inefficient to cycle through them, specially since I don't make a lot of mistakes. I am unable to find any clue online and the manual mentions only the interactive mode of usage.

Comment: How about?:  `M-x flyspell-buffer`

Comment: Thanks! It works. For reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877493/have-flyspell-mark-all-misspelled-words-even-those-not-written-during-the-curren